# data validation for SQLAlchemy declarative models

Tags: python, validation, model, sqlalchemy, cherrypy

I'm using CherryPy, Mako templates, and SQLAlchemy in a web app.  I'm coming from a Ruby on Rails background and I'm trying to set up some data validation for my models.  I can't figure out the best way to ensure, say, a 'name' field has a value when some other field has a value.  I tried using [SAValidation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SAValidation) but it allowed me to create new rows where a required column was blank, even when I used `validates_presence_of` on the column.  I've been looking at [WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/) but that seems to involve a lot of duplicated code--I already have my model class set up with the columns in the table, why do I need to repeat all those columns again just to say "hey this one needs a value"?  I'm coming from the "[skinny controller, fat model](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model)" mindset and have been looking for Rails-like methods in my model like `validates_presence_of` or `validates_length_of`.  How should I go about validating the data my model receives, and ensuring `Session.add`/`Session.merge` fail when the validations fail?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I ended up using WTForms after all.

Comment: How'd you get around the code duplication? Can you explain a bit how you're using it? I'm a rails dev as well but looking to develop an app with flask+sqlalchemy...I've seen WTForms but it seems a bit foreign to me in that you're always storing validation in the view...while it feels more valid (and more dry) to store it in the model.

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at the documentation for adding [validation methods](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#simple-validators).  You could just add an "update" method that takes the POST dict, makes sure that required keys are present, and uses the decorated validators to set the values (raising an error if anything is awry).

Comment: Validation methods only work for one field at a time. He obviously means validation that depends on relationship between fields.

Comment: Works with multiple fields by 

(a) list all the fields you want to validate in the decorator
`@validates('validates_presence_of', 'validates_length_of')`

(b) ensure your validation triggers on last declared field within the list of fields so the other fields have been set already
`if key == 'validates_length_of':  [code to validate]`

Answer (score 3):

I wrote [SAValidation](https://github.com/blazelibs/sqlalchemy-validation) for the specific purpose of avoiding code duplication when it comes to validating model data.  It works well for us, at least for our use cases.

In our tests, we have [examples of the model's setup](https://github.com/blazelibs/sqlalchemy-validation/blob/master/savalidation/tests/test_examples.py) and tests to show the validation works.

Answer (score 0):

[API Logic Server](https://github.com/valhuber/ApiLogicServer/blob/main/README.md) provides business rules for SQLAlchemy models.  This includes not only multi-field, multi-table validations, but multi-table validations.  It's open source.